# Create an extension in Magento for Web push Notifications

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I want to create an extension with web push notification in Magento. Purpose of this extension is to send notification on customer system even web site is not open.
I wanna to create an extension to add notification functionality like this site is providing

```
https://www.izooto.com
```

I am using the Google service worker for implementation.

We want to create functionality like Facebook or any other eCommerce site that send notification on user system even site not open.
I am not aware how we can send notification on each event like customer purchased an item or notification on customer login.

Please suggest how we can initiate this extension.I have integrated  with help of this link:

```
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en
```

I did lot of R&D on it and implemented basic example to send notification but how I can make notification data dynamic 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ZOE-Use magento events in your extension for dynamic data and fire push notification.

Comment: @Zoe ,Thanks for the reply.I know that is possible with events but not getting the way how to make content dynamic and pass to js file that will send notification..

Comment: use third party for push notification it's free & so easy i'm currently using it in my magento website.. (www.kairaliproducts.in)
https://onesignal.com

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on it this might solved your issue; 
http://inchoo.net/magento/push-notifications-magento/